# Searching exact woed in sublime text not working

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text and I want to search `.btn` in a CSS stylesheet, but I get unexpected results like `.btn-sm` too. I have turned on whole word but it seems not working properly...

How can Ido this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex search will do the trick:

```regex
\.btn(?![-|\w])
```

It searches for the literal sequence `.btn` with a negative lookahead to make sure the next character is not either a `-` symbol or a word character. This way the search *won't* match `.btnfoo`, for example (line 6 below).

[image: example]